# REACT - Hook make infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have a problem with an hooks.

When i make

```
     export default function Checkout() {
  const { readRemoteFile } = usePapaParse();
  const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState([]);

  const handleReadRemoteFile = file => {
    readRemoteFile(file, {
      complete: (results) => {
        setParsedCsvData(results.data);
          },
    });
    };
    handleReadRemoteFile(CSVsource);
    }
```

I have an infinite loop but when i make

```
     export default function Checkout() {
  const { readRemoteFile } = usePapaParse();
  const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState([]);

  const handleReadRemoteFile = file => {
    readRemoteFile(file, {
      complete: (results) => {
        console.log(results.data);
          },
    });
    };
    handleReadRemoteFile(CSVsource);
    }
```

I have'nt the problem.

Have you an idea ?
Thank's Yann.

Comment: Please show your entire component or the entire custom hook and how you're using it. My best guess is that `handleReadRemoteFile(CSVsource)` is ran on every render (and `setParsedCsvData()` updates the state, so the component rerenders when the file is read, causing a loop.

Comment: Sorry, i add the rest of component.

Comment: @Taxel yep, they might be using `useEffect` without the second argument of `[]` to only run it once: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Thanks, i can resolve the problem with useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

While the component code you posted is still incomplete (`CSVsource` is undefined, there's no return), I think the problem is visible now:

You're running `handleReadRemoteFile(CSVsource)` on every render (because you're calling it directly). When the file is read, you are setting `parsedCsvData`, which (because state updates and prop updates trigger a rerender) renders the component again, triggering `handleReadRemoteFile` once again...

### So what's the solution?

Data fetching is a classical example of using the `useEffect` hook. The following code should do what you want

```
const { readRemoteFile } = usePapaParse();
const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  readRemoteFile(CSVSource, {
    complete: results => setParsedCsvData(results.data);
  });
}, [CSVsource]); // rerun this whenever CSVSource changes.
```

Please read up on the `useEffect` hook [in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Note: there's one problem with the code I posted above. When the component is unmounted while the CSV is still loading, you will get an error "state update on unmounted component" as soon as the loading finished. To mitigate this, use the return function of `useEffect` in combination with a local variable.

So the final code looks like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  let stillMounted = true;
  readRemoteFile(CSVSource, {
    complete: results => {
       if(!stillMounted) return; // prevent update on unmounted component
       setParsedCsvData(results.data);
    }
  });
  return ()=>stillMounted = false; // this function is ran before the effect is ran again and on unmount
}, [CSVsource]);
```